# Select from execute block?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, firebird-3.0

Is is possible to select from execute block result? I want to perform some operation (sum etc..) from it.

```
 select t1.* 
 from 
   ( execute block 
     returns ( 
       OUT_VALUE integer ) 
    as 
    begin 
    ... 
    suspend; 
  end ) t1
```

or

```
 with   
 t1 as ( execute block ... ) 
   select * 
   from t1 
   order by 
     t1.sort_column
```

Neither does not work. Anyone has an advice? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is not possible to wrap an `execute block` in a select, but an `execute block` can produce a result set just like a normal select would. So depending on what you are trying to do, it is just a matter of moving all select logic **into** the `execute block`. Otherwise you will need to create a real selectable stored procedure, and use that.

Comment: I need that too. Goal is to run some PSQL without creating stored procedure and then select from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an independent stored procedure like

```
create procedure proc1
returns (
  OUT_VALUE integer 
) as
begin
   ... 
  suspend; 
end
```

and then select on this proc

```
select sum(OUT_VALUE)
from proc1
```